# Parquet file generated using polybase does not contain column names

Tags: azure, sql-server-2016, parquet, polybase

I have used the following query to create an external table in SQL 2016 with polybase.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.SampleExternal (
    DateId INT NULL,
    CalendarQuarter TINYINT NULL,
    FiscalQuarter TINYINT NULL)
WITH (LOCATION='/SampleExternal.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE=AzureStorage,
    FILE_FORMAT=ParquetFile);
```

Inserted the data to external table from local table and the parquet file was successfully generated in azure container.But while reading the parquet file ,coulmn names are shown as col-0,col-1.Is there any way to
add original coumn names in parquet file as given in external tables.
[Column Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qgjf.png)

Comment: same here if any one knows please reply.

Comment: I was trying to interface the data from PDW to Hadoop into polybase. but column name is not working. I tried to contact ms and received a reply. This is a bug and should be fixed with a hotfix.

Answer (score 0):

This seems 'as designed' in polybase. The consuming application has to do mapping from these numbered column names to meaningful column names. If the producing application is different than consumer app, they should handshake on the column mapping.